# I want to add a Field-handling capability from the "C Programming Language Book exercise 5-17"

Tags: c, sorting

This exercise tells us to make a Field-Handling capability into a string sorting program (i.e. '-2df -1n' sorts the 2nd column by letters then sorts the 1st column by numbers), the thing it that I don't know how to implement the sorting for the next flag, lemme explain:

```
---Names--- ---Last names--- ---Ages---
   Will          Smith           25
   Samuel        Johns           16
   Enrico        Pucci           39
   Lisa          Donald          16
```

And let's assume that I want to sort it with **-3n** (ages), we will get :

```
---Names--- ---Last names--- ---Ages---
   Enrico        Pucci           39
   Will          Smith           25
   Samuel        Johns           16
   Lisa          Donald          16
```

Then I wanna sort by **-1df** (names), And I want to get :

```
---Names--- ---Last names--- ---Ages---
   Enrico        Pucci           39
   Will          Smith           25
   Lisa          Donald          16
   Samuel        Johns           16
```

(Lisa and Samuel are swapped because L comes before S)
The problem is that I just want to swap elements that have the same **-3n**, which means that if Enrico and Will weren't sorted by name **BUT** sorted by age, we will not touch them, and since Lisa and Samuel have the same age, we can sort their names...

Those are the sort and comparison functions used:

```
void myqsort(void *lineptr[], int start, int end, int index, int (*comp)(void *, void *))
{
    // 'latest' holds the latest index where a swap happened
    int latest, i;
    if (start >= end)
        return;
    swap(lineptr, start, (start + end) / 2); // swap the first and middle element
    latest = start;
    for (i = start + 1; i <= end; i++) {
        // compare the splits of each string, so that it can handle fields
        if ((*comp)(strsplit(lineptr[i], '\t')[index], strsplit(lineptr[start], '\t')[index]) < 0)
            swap(lineptr, i, ++latest);
    }
    swap(lineptr, start, latest);
    myqsort(lineptr, start, latest - 1, index, comp);
    myqsort(lineptr, latest + 1, end, index, comp);
}
```

Code Explanation :
This function will sort strings using a quick sort algorithm, I might change how it works because `strsplit(lineptr[i], '\t')[index]` isn't that pretty, what it does is split the string at each `'\t'`and goes to the **index** split part, where **index = the number in the flag (-3df = 3)**

```
int mystrcmp(char *s, char *t)
{
    // NOTE: dir_order and fold are external variables
    // which are set to true if we get their flag (-3d)
    char a, b;
    do {
        if (dir_order) {
            while (!isblank(*s) && !isalnum(*s))
                s++;
            while (!isblank(*t) && !isalnum(*t))
                t++;
        }
        a = (fold) ? tolower(*s) : *s;
        b = (fold) ? tolower(*t) : *t;
        s++, t++;
    } while (a == b);
    return a - b;
}
```

I hope that you can help me and that I have given enough information, the code is pretty long so that why I didn't include it here, if you want it, just tell it to me !

Comment: How are you doing the sort itself - by passing a comparator function to qsort? You need to enhance your comparator to split the ties by using the next rule in the list. It might be worth showing us the sort and comparisons code.

Comment: Thanks. In your compare the splits line `if ((*comp)(strsplit(` you'll need to also check if the result is 0, and if it is then you'll need to compare the splits again for the next column in the order.